# Symfony 2.7: The 127.0.0.1 page isn’t working 127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: symfony

The form is displayed with different roles and permissions except that the server can not Symfony 2.7 processed the request (I do not know why !!).

> The 127.0.0.1 page isn’t working
>   127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

even though I used the command:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

here are my formType:

```
Class RoleType{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder

          ->add('groups', 'entity',array(
                                            'class' => 'GroupsBundle:Roles',
                                            'property' => 'name_role',
                                             'required' => false,
                                             'placeholder' => 'Choisir le role du votre groupe'
                                         )
           )


           ->add('permissions_role','entity',array(
                   'class' => 'GroupsBundle:Permissions',
                   'property' => 'name_permissions',
                   'multiple' => true,
                   'expanded' => true,
                   'required' => true
               )
               )
 ;
}
}

Class GroupType{



class GroupsType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('image', new ImagesType())
            ->add('name_groups','text',array('required' => true, 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Nom du groupe')))
            ->add('role', new RolesType())
        ;
    }
}
```

Here the code of controller:

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Groups();
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            //$em->getReference('MemberShipManagement\GroupsBundle\Entity\Groups',$entity.getId());
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('groups_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return $this->render('GroupsBundle:Groups:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

thank you to solve the problem

*Dev.log

```
[2016-07-12 00:23:49] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT p0_.id_per AS id_per0, p0_.nom_permisions AS nom_permisions1 FROM permissions p0_ [] []
[2016-07-12 00:23:49] doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT r0_.id AS id0, r0_.nom_roles AS nom_roles1 FROM roles r0_ WHERE r0_.id IN (?) [["0"]] []
[2016-07-12 01:51:58] php.DEBUG: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 (Connection refused) {"type":2,"file":"/home/syrine01/Desktop/Project_Console/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ServerCommand.php","line":59,"l
evel":28928} []
WARNING - Translation not found. 
Context: {"id":"Image","domain":"messages","locale":"fr"}
WARNING - Translation not found. 
Context: {"id":"File","domain":"messages","locale":"fr"}
WARNING - Translation not found. 
Context: {"id":"Name groups","domain":"messages","locale":"fr"}
WARNING - Translation not found. 
Context: {"id":"Nom du groupe","domain":"messages","locale":"fr"}
WARNING - Translation not found. 
Context: {"id":"Role","domain":"messages","locale":"fr"}
WARNING - Translation not found. 
Context: {"id":"Groups","domain":"messages","locale":"fr"}
WARNING - Translation not found. 
Context: {"id":"Choisir le role du votre groupe","domain":"messages","locale":"fr"}
WARNING - Translation not found. 
Context: {"id":"Permissions role","domain":"messages","locale":"fr"}
WARNING - Translation not found.
INFO - Matched route "groups_new". 
Context: {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"MemberShipManagement\\GroupsBundle\\Controller\\GroupsController::newAction","_route":"groups_new"},"request_uri":"http://127.0.0.1:8000/groups/new"}
DEPRECATED - The Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfProvider\CsrfProviderAdapter class is deprecated since version 2.4 and will be removed in version 3.0. Use the Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManager class instead.  +
INFO - Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.
DEPRECATED - MemberShipManagement\GroupsBundle\Form\GroupsType: The FormTypeInterface::setDefaultOptions() method is deprecated since version 2.7 and will be removed in 3.0. Use configureOptions() instead. This method will be added to the FormTypeInterface with Symfony 3.0.  +
DEPRECATED - MemberShipManagement\GroupsBundle\Form\ImagesType: The FormTypeInterface::setDefaultOptions() method is deprecated since version 2.7 and will be removed in 3.0. Use configureOptions() instead. This method will be added to the FormTypeInterface with Symfony 3.0.  +
DEPRECATED - MemberShipManagement\GroupsBundle\Form\RolesType: The FormTypeInterface::setDefaultOptions() method is deprecated since version 2.7 and will be removed in 3.0. Use configureOptions() instead. This method will be added to the FormTypeInterface with Symfony 3.0.  +
DEPRECATED - The "property" option is deprecated since version 2.7 and will be removed in 3.0. Use "choice_label" instead.
```

I have not done the translation of my website

the Config databse is:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
          driver:   pdo_mysql
          host:     "%database_host%"
          port:     "%database_port%"
          dbname:   "%database_name%"
          user:     "%database_user%"
          password: "%database_password%"
          charset:  UTF8
          unix_socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

//parameters
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: root
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
```

with this command I find my server encountered a problem

```
 sudo php app/console server:start -vvv
```

> [2016-07-12 06:02:10] php.DEBUG: fsockopen(): unable to connect to
>   127.0.0.1:8000 (Connection refused) {"type":2,"file":"/home/Cros/Desktop/Project_Console/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Command/ServerCommand.php","line":59,"level":28928}

Comment: We don't know why either! You must find and post the 500 error in the PHP logs.

Comment: I think I have a server connection problem by formualre against the page is displayed without problem.
this problem appears when I save the group information: name, role and permissions of the selected role, thank you

Answer (score 1):

**It is shown in the dev.log at the 3rd line**:

```
[2016-07-12 01:51:58] php.DEBUG: fsockopen(): unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:8000 (Connection refused) ...
```

Try to check your database informations and have a look to your parameters or config file in *app/config* directory to see if all database parameters are set correctly.
Currently, your database_port is set to 8000, maybe your must leave the value to null. 
Anyway try to check your database informations (database_host, database_port, database_user, database_password...). It may be the problem

Comment: I do not think so that the problem is at the config parameters, because I created the databse and the tables after the console.De more in my form the roles and permissions are displayed after the database,  no problem with the database